# C# CommandBuilder alternative or way to use CommandBuilder without a connection?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I need to (at runtime) build some SQL statements to update a database that I am NOT connected to.  Right now I am using a String.Format to build the query, but it's difficult to deal with all the different parameter cases (different datatypes, null, values, escaping, etc..).

What I'd like is to use CommandBuilder--but CommandBuilder requires a DataAdapter which requires a connection and I'm not connected to my database (this is a stand alone utility).

Is there a way to use CommandBuilder in a disconnected state or how can I build this well formatted SQL query in a way that will require me to write a minimal amount of code?

(Target DB is SQL Server)

Comment: So you're building commands in advance and *then* connect to DB to run them? Or u just build them?

Comment: I just build them -- my output is a text file that is run remotely by an SQL admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to use CommandBuilder in a disconnected state?

Unfortunately **NO**.

`SqlCommandBuilder` is designed to work with a `SqlDataAdapter` and a `SqlCommand` object, or just a `SqlCommand`, and from the [documenttation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.aspx) it **needs to connect to the database to retrieve information shema**.

Comment: That's too bad--I've tried to re-word my question so as to remove the subjective/opinion part out of this.  I'm just looking for an alternative to rewriting CommandBuilder from scratch (or the parts of it that I need).

Comment: @scotru +1 For edit. I hope my comment didn't offensed you. The second part of the question makes much more sense know, and is OK with SO rules. Unfortunately, I have no answer for this one ;-)

Comment: I can't find a good solution to this.  I rewrote the functionality I needed.